# Ubuntu docker base image spawns two images?

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I followed a really simple get-started intro video to docker, and the "hello world" example to start with looks like this:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update
CMD ["echo","hui there"]
```

I then build with:

```
 sudo docker build .
```

everything goes as planned. Now I run `sudo docker images`:

```
ask@Garsy:~/Notes/TA/AppliedInfoSec/docker$ sudo docker images
REPOSITORY   TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED          SIZE
<none>       <none>    890bf2a53fe0   10 seconds ago   104MB
ubuntu       latest    fb52e22af1b0   4 weeks ago      72.8MB
```

This is strange, it seems like the command created two images for me?
(this top image was not there before)

Why does this happen? is it simply the base image I am pulling from thta does this, and why would it do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `ubuntu:latest` image is the base image, as specified by `FROM ubuntu` in your container file. The untagged image, `890bf2a53fe0`, is the image created by `docker build`.

The base image is present because building on top of it involves pulling it; if you try building again you’ll notice that it doesn’t get pulled again, unless you remove it beforehand. See also the creation timestamps which give a hint as to which image was created by your `docker build` invocation.

Comment: So, the unnamed image is the onne that is created by me running `build`? what is the other docker image then created from? And how do I do what I want to, to create a single docker image which I can run?

Comment: The other Docker image is pulled from a remote repository. You have a single Docker image which you can run: `docker run 890bf2a53fe0`.